# Template argument not deduced for inner class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class myclass
{
    T something;
public:
    myclass(T something) : something{ something }
    { }

    struct result
    {
        T value;
    };

    result get_result()
    {
        return{ something };
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const typename myclass<T>::result& res)
{
    return stream << res.value;
}

int main()
{
    myclass<int> m(0);
    std::cout << m.get_result() << "\n";
}
```

In this case neither gcc nor msvc find the overloaded stream operator when I put in a result (which is dependent on a templated outer class). Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: What is error message diplay by compiler ?

Comment: There's simply no general way for the compiler to figure out a unique type to deduce.

Comment: The practical problem is that the nested type may not be unique: `template< > class myclass<int> { using result = myclass<float>::result`. In this case, two instantiations share a single nested type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`T` is non-deductible for `myclass<T>::result`.

You may define `operator<<` inside the class to solve your issue:

```
struct result
{
    T value;


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const result& res)
    {
        return stream << res.value;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4931da75de694fed)